# R gives me the error "contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels" running an mlogit model, but all my factors have 2 levels

Tags: r, conjoint-analysis, mlogit

I have a set of results from a choice experiment that I am trying to analyse using the mlogit function in R.  My data set is shown below, where each STR value represents the three choices in a single choice experiment, 'CHOICE' is a binary variable indicating which the participant selected, and columns C-G detail the attributes of each choice (D-G being binary variables - 1=yes, 0=no).

[image: image of data set]

I am trying to run the model as:

```
m <- mlogit(CHOICE ~ PRICE + GreenStatement + Certification +
            MediumBrand + HighBrand,
            SP1, choice = "CHOICE", shape = "long", alt.levels = "STR")
```

but get the error "contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels".  I have tried running 'as.factor' on all the variables, so they are different factors, and asking R to display a data summary tells me that they all have 2 or more levels.  But I still get this error.  Would anyone please be able to help me identify (and fix!) the source of this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that everything you think is a factor is? try putting as.factor into the mlogit function, as in mlogit(CHOICE ~ PRICE + as.factor(GreenStatement) ...

Comment: What do `is.factor(SP1$CHOICE)` and `unique(SP1$CHOICE)` and `levels(SP1$CHOICE)` return?

Comment: Do that for all of them. Especially `MediumBrand` since from the screen cap it looks like a column of zeroes

Comment: They all give me the same output: 
is.factor(VARIABLE)
[1] TRUE
;
unique(VARIABLE)
[1] 0 1
Levels: 0 1
;
 levels(VARIABLE)
[1] "0" "1"

Comment: The help on `mlogit` doesn't list an `alt.levels` argument -- what does it do?

Answer (score 10):

See Answer Here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171246/error-in-contrasts-when-defining-a-linear-model-in-r

There are factors that you are using that either have only 1 distinct value or are NA

Comment: And you can check by using, say, summary() on all of your factor variables.

Comment: Here's a way to check this if `dt` is a `data.table`: `char.factor.cols <- 
    names(which(sapply(dt, function(x) is.character(x) | is.factor(x))));
for(i in char.factor.cols) cat(i, dt[, .N, i][, .N], "\n")`

Comment: for a plain data frame, `df`, you can use: `which(sapply(df, function(x) (is.character(x) | is.factor(x)) & length(unique(x))<2))`